# With same timestamp firestore is returning the same result on different pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have written the following query for extracting documents from firestore.

```
await ctx.db
      .collection("orderCollection")
      .orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
      .orderBy("uuid")
      .where(key, "==", ctx.uid)
      .where("timeStamp", "<", parseInt(timeStamp))
      .startAfter(lastResultUUID)
      .withConverter(StoreOwnerROrderConvertor)
      .limit(limitNum)
      .get();
```

OrderCollection contains the info about the placed orders.
Multiple orders are placed at the same time. Every order has unique ID(UUID). On each page we will extract limitNum pages. lastResultUUID contains the UUID of the last extracted document. Suppose limitNum=5. And there are 10 orders placed at the same time so all order have same timestamp.The timestamp is in milliseconds. On page-1 I receive the 5 results and lastResultUUID is empty, but on page-2, I receive the same 5 results. While lastResultUUID contains the UUID of 5th item from the page-1. I am expecting the next 5 order info.

Answer (score 2):

`.startAfter()` compares "lastResultUUID" with "timeStamp" in your code. You have to put variables in a same order as you use `.orderBy()` fields like below:

```js
.startAfter(lastResultTimeStamp, lastResultUUID)
```

Or just pass whole `DocumentSnapshot<T>`:

```js
.startAfter(lastDocumentSnapshot)
```

Just in case, the document you save to database is not a `DocumentSnapshot<T>`! Read documentation if you don't know what is `DocumentSnapshot<T>` so you know what to pass to method like `.startAfter()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am taking approach 1.  What should be the value of lastResultTimeStamp while serving the first page? lastResultUUID's value is ''(empty string) while serving the first page.

Comment: @user1927603 FIrst query should not have any `.startAfter()` methods. Second query if you want to have paginated result should have `.startAfter()` method.